# netmask converting, what wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, strtok

Can someone tell me where did I go wrong of the following code?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char str[35]={0};
  char b[15]="255.255.255.255";
  nmcalc(b,str);
    return 0;
}

void nmcalc(char str[],char b[35]) {
  char *delim = ".";
  char *pch;
  char a[8]={0};
  int num;
  int i =0;

  pch = strtok(str,delim);
  while (pch != NULL){
    i++;
    num=atoi(pch);
    decToBinStr8bit(num,a);
    strcat(b,a);
    if(i!=3){
        strcat(b,".");
    }
    pch = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }     
}

void decToBinStr8bit(int n,char str[]){
    int c, k;
    strcpy(str,"");
    for (c = 7; c >= 0; c--) {
        k = n >> c;

            if (k & 1)
              strcat(str,"1");
        else
              strcat(str,"0");
    }
}
```

It seems a infinite loop.

Comment: Please note, you should define `nmcalc` and `decToBinStr8bit` before `main` function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is , with a definition like

```
char b[15]="255.255.255.255";
```

you miss the null-terminator, so technically `b` is not a *string*, and passing it as the argument for string handling functions will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as the functions will go past the allocated memory in search of the end of the *string*.

For better, leave the size allocation to the compiler, like

```
 char b[ ]="255.255.255.255"; // array incldes the null-terminator.
```

or, if you *have to* supply the size yourself, remember to include the null-terminator in calculation, something like

```
  #define ARRSIZ 16
  char b[ARRSIZ]="255.255.255.255";
```

The same goes for all the arrays that need to be used as *strings*.

---

*Note: Please stop using confusing variable names.*

```
  func(a,b);

  int func(int b, int a) {....
```

*does not serve any meaningful purpose other that confusing people (including you, at some later time)*.

Comment: Likewise `a` and `str` have insufficient space to hold the results with the NUL terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the null-terminator(s) in the following codes.

`char b[15]="255.255.255.255";` the size should be `16`.

Also `char a[8]={0};` the size should be `9`or instead of `strcat(a,b)` you can use the following:

`strncat(b, a, 8);` but I suggest you to use null-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in the above program:-

1. You need to account for Null whenever you are using char array. So change str[35] to str[36], b[15] to b[16], b[35] to b[36], a[8] to a[9].
2. Change condition from if(i!=3) to if(i<=3).

Program should start working. It works for me. I could see converted netmask in binary.